# How to take ownership of a client id and secret requested by another person?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I wanted to use the same client id and secret from an existing client application which actually belongs to another person and he is no longer with the organization. How can I view that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually explained in the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/access-client-app-id-task):

> You must have the Organization Administrator privileges of the master
> organization, or must be the owner of the client application to access
> the credentials.
>
> To obtain the credentials of a client application:
>
> 1. From the left navigation pane in Anypoint Platform, click Management Center > API Manager.
> 2. On the left navigation in API Manager, click Client Applications.
> 3. From the details pane, click the application for which you want to view the client credentials.
> 4. The client ID and client secret credentials for the selected application appear on the right of the window.